# is it possible to encourage threads to line up without forcing it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, memory-barriers

I have a single atomic variable that multiple threads are loading, they perform some local calculations on it, then call an atomically fetch_and on it. They check that they were able to make there change before another thread did, if not, repeat using the updated value returned from fetch_and

Works a lot faster than a locked version. But would be nice if I could encourage multiple threads to align and not load the atomic number until fetch_and completes without forcing it.

Is this possible? Thinking it might be using a memory fence or two?

Comment: How does this run faster than a single threaded version as you seem to be saying only 1 thread out of all the running threads can update the shared atomic?

Comment: Getting into specifics, I'm doing bitwise operations on the atomic, then checking if successful. Different threads typically twiddle different bits and only check that no other thread has touched one specific bit. So most of the time they are able to do their own things separately only occasionally stepping on each other's feet. And while locks are cheap, lock contention is not, and a single atomic is faster, in fact I can usually skip the initial load and only fetch_and. That's my guess. In benchmarks runs about 10 times faster than with lock.

Comment: *They check that they were able to make there change before another thread did* - Would it be useful to have threads use CAS to apply changes?  i.e. to use CAS to build a custom atomic RMW.  Or is the AND operation still useful?  (Also note that x86 doesn't have hardware fetch_and, only atomic `and` that doesn't return the old value, if that matters, so using the return value of fetch_and forces compilers to emulate it using a CAS retry loop internally).  Manual CAS doesn't solve the problem of wasted work if you have threads contending so might not be helpful.

Comment: BTW, memory barriers only order *this* core's access to coherent cache.  If you know what you're looking for, you can spin read-only until you see a value that makes "success" possible, whatever that means.  Still not clear on exactly what's being repeated (computation or just another atomic fetch_and); an example would help.

Comment: If the atomic version performs better than locked version in your particular test then it does not mean that in some other test it is not directly opposite or that some third (for example asynchronous queued) version can't be even better than either for actual usage of concurrency (as tests usually miss some aspect).

Comment: Yeah, tried testing it a little bit more, such as simulating bad situations. Also I realize that I didn't need the verify step if I used a lock because I could also grab the first one on the first try. So I cut out a lot of that code. Locked certain now runs faster. Also, every once in a while, atomic version will slow to a crawl. So I'm going ahead with the locked version. Maybe I'll post another comment with the complete code to see if it can be optimized even further. Still a bottleneck in some circumstances. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no point. If two threads don't try to do this at the same time, they'll make perfect progress. If two threads do try to do this at the same time, one of them will have to wait in some way. What way that other thread waits has no effect on performance.

If each thread needs about the same amount of time between accesses to the atomic variable, they'll line up naturally because they'll proceed past the first such access one at a time. If threads need different amounts of time, no attempt to line them up could possibly succeed. The only way to keep two threads from arriving at the same time is to slow one of them down and the consequence of them arriving at the same time is already that one of them slows down.

If the local calculations take so long that there's any risk that your code will spend a lot of time doing calculations that are thrown away, switch to using a lock.